# Datatable or any JQuery Plugin that supports multiple row pagination in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, datatable, pagination

I am currently using DataTable in which the pagination will cut off at the next page if the row has more than 2 rowspan due to its pageLength. I have an rough example that I created here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kexns4eh/

Also, [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiG6d.png) shows the problem I faced.

I am hiding data because I will need the values in the show function. Is there any way in DataTable or any other plugin to group these three data together or group multiple `<tbody>` for pagination? I would appreciate any suggestion, thank you!

Comment: You can use JSGrid.

Comment: **DataTables does not support rowspans or colspans**! If you google around you will see this discussed and clearly stated multiple times over the years on datatables.net, and you will see perhaps 50 entries here on SO. Why not just wrap the names into styled `<span>`'s or insert a `<table>` inside the `<td>`?

Comment: @davidkonrad Apologies for the repeated question, I did not manage to find the answers from those previous questions so I try to ask again. I am quite unfamilar with this `<span>` tag, do you mind explaining how to style the `<td>` such that the titles will be together? Thank you very much.

Comment: @EllenaLee, Dont apologize, I will apologize the bold text, could be interpreted wrong; it just seem to be a consecutively issue when people start using datatables. Here is an updated fiddle with what i meant -> **https://jsfiddle.net/kexns4eh/2/** have also corrected the header so the table is initialised. It is not perfect, look to the right to see the CSS, the best is propably a fixed width for the column with names, but it work with datatables, and you can decrease the number of rows with 66% and completely avoid all the hidden `<td>`'s ...

Comment: @davidkonrad Ah, I get it now! Thank you very much for the help! :D